# Is würde dir gefallen equivalent to möchtest?

Tags: english-to-german

I want to express the phrases below in German. Note, one is in English and the other in Spanish.

> What would you like to eat?

> Qué te gustaría comer?

Now, I know that I can say:
Was möchtest du essen?

However, I want the German phrase to match as closely as possible to the above. Like for example word for word. That means I want to use the Konjunktiv II with the helper verb. So I thought of this.

> Was würde dir essen gefallen?

Also.. my questions are. First, is this correct syntactically? And is the meaning equivalent with the more typical Was möchtest du essen?

Vielen Dank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could phrase it as

> Was würde dir zu essen gefallen?

But no. Don't do that. This is completely unidiomatic and it means a slightly different thing: *"What to eat" would you like?*

In German, you can reorder it as

> Was zu essen würde dir gefallen?

and it becomes more aligned to its actual meaning. Still uncommon.

This is because *gefallen* is a tricky verb that has **the subject** as its complement. Not an object. This is very different to English *to like* and more similar to Spanish *gustar*. German *mögen* is the equivalent of English *to like* as it has the accusative object as its complement. *Möchtest* is actually a Konjunktiv II form of *mögen*.

Comment: The literal meaning of "gefallen" is "to be pleasing to", but it's translated with "to like" with a subject-object switch. Apparently "gustar" works the same way. The English "like" combines the functions of "gefallen" and "mögen", so it depends on circumstances which would be a better translation in German.